# Split a single row into multiple rows based on date range in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, recursive-query

my SQL server table structure is some what like below

```
FROM_Currency   To_Currency   ExchangeRate   StartDate    EndDate
EUR               GBP            33.5        2018-03-31    2018-04-30
USD               EUR            22.9        2019-01-31    2019-02-28
```

like this have historical exchange rate data for multiple currencies and exchange rate for over 3 years,
as shown in above table we have start date and enddate for each currency rate in a range of 1 month ,what i need is to basically split it into each day ,so basically need exchange rate daily ,for ex: for 1st record i need 30 rows which should say from_currency as EUR and To_currency as GBP and exchange rate as 33.5 and new date column should be increment date starting from 2018-03-31 to 2018-04-30 .

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: Sounds like you should be joining to a [Calendar Table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/bones-of-sql-the-calendar-table)

Comment: Please search for `[tsql] missing dates` and see if you can find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select 
         from_currency, 
         to_currency, 
         exchange_rage, 
         startDate, 
         endDate, 
         startDate currentDate
    from mytable t
    union all
    select 
         from_currency, 
         to_currency, 
         exchange_rage, 
         startDate, 
         endDate, 
         dateadd(day, 1, currentDate)
    from cte
    where currentDate < endDate
)
select from_currency, to_currency, exchange_rage, currentDate from cte
```

If your any of your periods span over more 100 days, then you need to add `option(maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query.